# NullPointerException for checking token in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, nullpointerexception, jwt, token

I'm using jwt token for authorization and when I send a request with the token I get null pointer exception and 500 error. How to fix this? I can get token for authorization, but can't use its.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.ilya.testapp.security.JwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(JwtTokenProvider.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ilya.testapp.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]

    ...
```

Controller for login:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/auth/")
public class AuthenticationRestControllerV1 {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public AuthenticationRestControllerV1(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("login")
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequestDto requestDto) {
        try {
            String username = requestDto.getUsername();
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, requestDto.getPassword()));
            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");
            }

            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, user.getRoleList());

            Map<Object, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("username", username);
            response.put("token", token);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }




    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


}
```

JwtTokenFilter:

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) req);
        System.out.println("req = "+req+" token1 = "+token);
        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {

            Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
            if (auth != null) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

JwtTokenProvider:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
    private long validityInMilliseconds;


    private UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;

    public JwtTokenProvider() {
    }

    public JwtTokenProvider(UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService) {
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
    }

    public JwtTokenProvider(String secret, long validityInMilliseconds, UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService) {
        this.secret = secret;
        this.validityInMilliseconds = validityInMilliseconds;
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    public String createToken(String username, List<String> roles){
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        claims.put("roles",roles);

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliseconds);

        return Jwts.builder()//
                .setClaims(claims)//
                .setIssuedAt(now)//
                .setExpiration(validity)//
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)//
                .compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.userPrincipalDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getUsername(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getUsername(String token){
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);

            if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer_")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

JwtConfigurer:

```
public class JwtConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtConfigurer(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

UserPrincipalDetailService:

```
@Service
public class UserPrincipalDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserPrincipalDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");
        }

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(user);
        return userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

UserPrincipal:

```
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {
    private User user;

    public UserPrincipal(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        // Extract list of permissions (name)
        this.user.getPermissionList().forEach(p -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p);
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        // Extract list of roles (ROLE_name)
        this.user.getRoleList().forEach(r -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + r);
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.user.getActive() == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved it? Same problem

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, because you deleted all line-numbers. But in the end you have a NullPointerException in your getAuthentication method in JWTTokenprovider.  Is your getUsername(token) method broken?